# Remove editions of Windows 7 Iso

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image, setup, wim

I downloaded an ISO of Windows 7 64 bits, I have a problem: I saw 4 editions in .clg files (home basic, premium, professional and ultimate), I opened `install.wim` with 7zip and I saw folders called 1,2,3 and 4. I suppose numbers are the 4 editions I mentioned.
How to remove editions from ISO? My problem is those editions makes iso size be up to 5.5 GB. I just need ultimate, no more editions needed.

Comment: Where did you download the ISO from? Did you use the [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) to do so? The media creation tool will help you get only the version you need.

Comment: [Easier just to download the specific version you need from Microsoft](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062)

Comment: I downloaded it from http://www.intercambiosvirtuales.org/sistemas-operativos/win7-sp1-abril-2015-es (site is in spanish). I cannot download it from Microsoft because I'll waste GB of my quota (I have a limited quota for normal speed and an unlimited one for a slower speed), on the other hand, the media creation tool of Windows 7 requires a genuine serial key before download, I don't have a legal copy of Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First run `Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:DVDDRIVELETTER:\sources\install.wim` to see which index the Edition has you want to have alone:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.17029
>
> Details for image : E:\sources\install.wim
>
> Index : 1 Name : Windows 7 HOMEBASIC Description : Windows 7 HOMEBASIC
>   Size : 11.623.452.494 bytes
>
> Index : 2 Name : Windows 7 HOMEPREMIUM Description : Windows 7
>   HOMEPREMIUM Size : 12.136.659.100 bytes
>
> Index : 3 Name : Windows 7 PROFESSIONAL Description : Windows 7
>   PROFESSIONAL Size : 12.037.929.390 bytes
>
> Index : 4 Name : Windows 7 ULTIMATE Description : Windows 7 ULTIMATE
>   Size : 12.200.638.813 bytes
>
> The operation completed successfully.

You want ultimate so run this command with the index 4 for Ultimate:

```
Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:DVDDRIVELETTER:\sources\install.wim /SourceIndex:4 /DestinationImageFile:C:\Win7Ultimate\sources\install.wim /DestinationName:"Windows 7 Ultimate"
```

This new ISO should now only include the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: `/Export-Image` causes error 87 The export-image is unknown

Comment: install the Win8.1/win10 ADK (Deployment Tools) and run the deployment tools CMD and run the DISM command now

Comment: New comment (not related with first comment): If `install.wim` contains only one edition of Windows, Do I have to delete .clg files of editions different to ultimate?

Comment: the clg is only used by the Windows System Image Manager. you can ignore the files. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825092.aspx

Comment: During Export-Image, Can we give comma separated index numbers as SourceIndex if we want more than one edition in the DestinationImageFile ?

Comment: @TsYYaYY1ud121a If DISM throws an error for either of the above commands, then you should try [installing the Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) and using the version of DISM included along with it. Sometimes the DISM included with your Windows install runs into weird issues on newer images.

Comment: @magicandre1981 ignore or delete? (in case only one edition of Windows) thanks